# Error installing libcrypt11 for spotify

Tags: apt, 15.10, files

I'm trying to get Spotify working on Ubuntu 15.10. I've tried installing `libgcrypt11` as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgcrypt11/+bug/1452216), but it fails:

```
jornh@PC1937:~$ sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

The log in `/var/log/dpkg.log` does not contain anything useful. Any suggestions on what to do next would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

indicates the `.deb` archive `libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb` is in the current directory i.e. the directory from where you are running the command which clearly is not there.

To solve this, You need to use the appropriate path to the directory where the file is stored e.g.:

```
sudo dpkg -i /foo/bar/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

or `cd` into the directory containing the file and then run e.g.:

```
cd /foo/bar && sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

**Test:**

I don't have any file `libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb` in the current directory, so i get:

```
% sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb

dpkg: error processing archive libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: If anyone is interested, I made a Salt script that will install this and spotify: https://github.com/jorn86/workstation/blob/master/spotify/init.sls

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get update      
 wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
 sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Explanation needed

Comment: The URL provided gives 404 for me, but you can find and manually download the package through the link in my question.